# Figuring out problematic brackets

Tags: django, reactjs, serialization, axios

Hi I have the following scenario:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

data = {key: ['a', 'b']} 
axios.get('url', {
   params: data,
   paramsSerializer: function(params) {
      return queryString.stringyfy(params, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})
   },
   headers: headers
}
```

On my django end when i get this:

```
request.GET = <QueryDict: {'key[]': ['a', 'b']} >
```

I am not sure how the mysterious '[]' came about and when i followed online solutions to use queryString, it does not seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: Its very mysterious, indeed.